# Can I use my second ethernet port to bridge the first?

Tags: networking, network-bridge

For reasons of architectural design and the way people installed the phone lines in the 80s, my desktop and the router are a long way apart. I ran CAT5 out to the desktop and that works great but wireless access near my desktop (for my phone/tablet/etc) a big pain in the bottom.

The main issue is my phone dropping back to 2G, interfering with my speakers and causing ***THEMOSTANNOYINGNOISEINTHEWORLD***.

Now my desktop has two network ports. I know what you're thinking, I'm a very lucky boy. I don't mean to boast, but I also have a cheapy little access point. It can either extend wirelessly (at painfully slow speeds) or I can plug in an ethernet cable and run at 150mpbs. I'd prefer the second :)

What I would *like* to do is plug the access port into eth1 and bridge eth1 to the network eth0 is connected to, without interfering my desktop's connection on eth0.

I'm not sure if this is possible but if it is, please give me a kick in the right direction.

Comment: I should point out that "bridge" might not be the right term. I have no interest in inspecting the traffic going to and from eth1 - I just want to bounce it down eth0 (while maintaining my connection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bridge connections you need [bridge-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bridge-utils).

Create a virtual bridge:
`root@bridge:~> brctl addbr br0`

Add interfaces:
`root@bridge:~> brctl addif br0 eth0`
`root@bridge:~> brctl addif br0 eth1`

Bounce them:
`root@bridge:~> ifconfig eth0 down`
`root@bridge:~> ifconfig eth1 down`
`root@bridge:~> ifconfig eth0 up`
`root@bridge:~> ifconfig eth1 up`

Make sure the bridge interface is up:
`root@bridge:~> ifconfig br0 up`

Reference material for further reading such as adding to startup or scripting the process [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Ethernet-Bridge-netfilter-HOWTO-3.html).  Or if you prefer the Ubuntu documentation, it's [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge).